# Grid of HTML objects in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to render ten 3d meshes with the [trimesh python library](https://trimsh.org) inside a Jupyter notebook and display them in 2x5 grid.

Following sample code shows ten Trimesh scenes, rendered one by one below each other.

```
import trimesh
import numpy as np
from IPython import display

for i in range(10):
    box = trimesh.creation.box(
            transform=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 2], 
                                [0, 1, 0, 2], 
                                [0, 0, 1, 2], 
                                [0, 0, 0, 2]], dtype=np.float64))
    sphere = trimesh.creation.icosphere()

    scene = trimesh.Scene([box, sphere])
    display.display(scene.show())
```

Result is shown below.

[image]

How can I update the code to reduce rows to 5 and make two scenes appear in each row?

I'd like to have the option to rotate each scene independently.

Desired result

[image]